# How to test if browser support keyframe stepped animation?

Tags: javascript, ipad, css, css-animations, modernizr

I've found that the browser that runs on ios simulator / xcode ios simulator on Mac OSX version 6.1 (10B141) doesn't show my stepped curved animation, the following:

http://jsbin.com/lebum/1/edit

By using Modernizr, I can test for cssanimation, but the truth is, the following works fine:

```
.balance {
    animation-name: balance;
    -webkit-animation-name: balance;    

    animation-duration: 0.8s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;

    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes balance {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);   
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);   
    }                       
}
```

I also noticed that, by doing the animation differently using percentage stages like the previous example (but not like the stepped animation that I want to achieve using from and to):

http://jsbin.com/muyeguba/4/

- even thought the animation is not exactly what I want, it's supported on ios safari. If I could figure if to and from is supported, would be awesome

I've not runned a new test, changing to and from, to 0% and 100% instead, but the issue is the same. Nothing appears on screen:

http://jsbin.com/lebum/3/

Which, leads me to believe that the only way around this, is to target this browser by using javascript and checking the browser agent ?

So, by running the following:

```
alert("User-agent header sent: " + navigator.userAgent);
```

I get:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad: CPU OS 6_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKi/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B141 Safari/8536.25
```

Any hints on how to target the lack of support for this type of animation ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make this work with this other stripe (The reason why I do it with percentages, is because I need this responsive):

http://jsbin.com/muyeguba/17/

** This definitely works for this stripe but not on the original one. So applying the same:

http://jsbin.com/muyeguba/19/

it doesn't work! Why ? Maybe a bug on safari ?!

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not supported by the browser, it is trivial to test for it - we just need to check what the parsed style is, using [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle)

Just add something like the following

```
var styles = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.animate'));
var itWorks = !!(styles.animation || styles.webkitAnimation)
```

That will check to see if the values returned are not empty, and therefore were parsed correctly.

*note: This assumes getComputedStyle and querySelector support, so you may also want to check for those.*

As for why it is not working, I would wager a hefty sum that the original image is too large for safari

Comment: thanks for looking! Unfortunately on the iPad (xcode ios simulator on Mac OSX version 6.1 (10B141)) itWorks always returns false, even when the animation runs like the following http://jsbin.com/muyeguba/21